# How to populate the tableviewCell to another viewcontroller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitableview

I'm developing a Bluetooth LE apps. In my `ViewController`, I have a action button (Search) if I pressed a action button the list of available BLE devices names are shown in the tableview that works fine. Now I want to access the `TableViewCell` (if I click a device name the supporting services are populating in another `ViewController`) to get services that are supported by the Bluetooth Low energy device. My question is How to access the device name in `TableViewCell` (populating) and how to get the supported services (for eg- alert, TxPwr, Battery) from BLE.. If I click a cell (device name) then I want to know the list of supported services. Give me an idea. Device is my mutable array. My question is how to populate the `TableViewCell` to my another `ViewController`...

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad 
  { 
     [super viewDidLoad]; 
     peripheralManager=[[PeripheralManager alloc]init]; 
     self.label.text = @"" 
     [self.deviceTable reloadData]; 
     device=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];     
  }
```

**TableView**

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{ 
    return 1; 
} 

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
    return [device count]; 
} 

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
   static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell"; 
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
   if(cell==nil) 
   { 
      cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
   } 

   cell.textLabel.text=[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
   cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton; 
   return cell; 
} 


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableDetails" sender:[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
//NSString *deviceName = [device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//secondViewController *svController=[[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    //svController.deviceName=deviceName;
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:svController animated:YES];
    // svController=nil;
  }
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
       {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TableDetails"]) {
    [segue.destinationViewController setDeviceName:(NSString *)sender];
       }
 }
```

Comment: Actually, "tomi2711" did most of the editing work. See the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose all you need/want from the selected (user tapped) table view cell is device name came from your mutable array named 'device'

If 'populating' means to let the newly loaded view controller, the destination view controller of 'TableDetails' segue, know the device name,

- Pass device name to sender: argument of performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:
- Device name could come from cell.textLabel.text or [device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], as you've already done in a different method
- Let's say the name of the newly loaded view controller has a class name **DeviceDetailViewController**, for example
- Add @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *deviceName; to **DeviceDetailViewController**
- Override -prepareForSegue:sender: method of the view controller performing the segue and pass the device name comes as sender argument to the destination view controller of the segue in this way:
- destinationViewController @property has the newly loaded instance of DeviceDetailViewController by Storyboard if you have configured it properly in Storyboard design such as giving a new class name to the segue destination view controller
- setDeviceName: method is magically available by declaration of @property (...) deviceName; declaration if you are using the latest version of Xcode

**DeviceDetailViewController**

```
@interface DeviceDetailViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *deviceName;
@end
```

**TableView**

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TableDetails"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setDeviceName:(NSString *)sender];
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    // UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableDetails" sender:[device objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
}
```

Now you can do whatever you want with deviceName @property of DeviceDetailViewController in the class implementation.

Comment: in the second view controller back button is not working with a single touch..if i click two times means it will goes to the main view controller

Comment: in output:Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <secondViewController: 0xce82090>

Comment: How did you setup the back button in the second view controller? If style of 'TableDetails' segue is Push, back button will be automatically setup if the first view controller is in a UINavigationController unless you've set self.navigationItem's backBarButtonItem or leftBarButtonItem properties in the second view controller. In short, behavior of [back] button is all about what/how you did in the second view controller.

Comment: in output:Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <secondViewController: 0xce82090> – what is this?

Comment: @Ios_learner that could be caused by many different reasons that I can't exactly tell. However, in this case, i suspect you tried to push/pop navigation stack in unbalanced manner such as, pushing a view controller to the navigation stack while pop animation is still on-going.

Comment: @Ios_learner Anyhow, I tried to simulate what you've tried, or should try. Please find the example at the [link]( http://www.iosappdev.co.kr/iosappdev/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/SOSampleMasterDetail.zip) It simply lists 'device 1' and device 2' in the first view controller, and the second view controller lists 'device n - detail 1', 'device n - detail 2', 'device n - detail 3', according to which device name you've chosen in the first table view.

Comment: thanks your helping its really help me..thanks alot..thanks for your timing,,